# Is this what a synchronized method really is?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Probably a very basic question but I'm still in doubt.
Am I correct in assuming that

```
public synchronized void doSynchronized() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Is exactly the same as:

```
public void doSynchronized() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

???

Comment: Yes both remain same.

Comment: [Java Language Specification §17.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1) *"A `synchronized` method (§8.4.3.6) automatically [..] locks the monitor associated with the instance for which it was invoked (that is, the object that will be known as `this` during execution of the body of the method)"*

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Everything else in this answer is just because it hast to be at least 30 characters to be submitted.

Comment: @VirajNalawade, Maybe not as helpful as it could be, but it does directly answer the question that was asked, and it does not comment on the question at all.

Comment: @jameslarge yes right.. sorry my bad..